# Problems in Generating FIle by wsdl2java

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

there are some strange brain racked occurring to me. 
In a given xsd file,we find a xml element that says as below:

```
<xsd:element name="getAllOperationsSystemsRequest">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

and a wsdl operation is linked to the element

```
   <wsdl:operation name="getAllOperationsSystems">
     <wsdl:input message="tns:getAllOperationsSystemsRequest"/>
     <wsdl:output message="tns:getAllOperationsSystemsResponse"/>
     <wsdl:fault name="getAllOperationsSystemsException" message="tns:getAllOperationsSystemsException"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
```

Apparently , getAllOperationsSystemsRequest is not bound to any known type ( the attribute "type" is missing.
As the result,after we exeucte wsdl2java tool,we finally get a method definition :

```
public org.tmforum.mtop.mri.xsd.osr.v1.MultipleObjectsResponseType getAllOperationsSystems(
    javax.xml.ws.Holder<org.tmforum.mtop.fmw.xsd.hdr.v1.Header> mtopHeader,
    java.lang.**Object** mtopBody
  )throws GetAllOperationsSystemsException
```

An Object instead of OperationsSystemsRequest is generated as the input parameter type,(actually the OperationsSystemsRequest  never come into existence.

Finally ,we get a bold runtime error in marshall/unmarshall

**Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: Instance of "javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement" is substituting "java.lang.Object", but "javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement" is bound to an anonymous type.**

I am really appreciated anyone for information to solve it. Tnanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Per XML Schema spec, the "type" for the getAllOperationsSystemsRequest element is an xsd:anyType.   Basically, anything.  That is why Object is generated in the code.   The code generators generate for types, not elements (mostly).  If the type is only represented in an element, then it would get an @XmlRootElement annotation, but for the most part, you have to think about the types.

I would recommend changing the schema to:

```
<xsd:element name="getAllOperationsSystemsRequest">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

That should generate a type and restrict the element to being an empty element.